# Cashing-in overseas cheques

Tags: check, international

I am currently in Australia, but I will be leaving soon. I expect some insurance reimbursements, which will be in form of a cheque, as I have no Australian bank account.
There might be the case, that the insurance sends out a cheque after I have left, so the cheque will be mailed to Europe. They really only do Aussie bank accounts or cheques.

Will I be able to cash-in an oversea's cheque in my home country?

However, as I didn't find a lot of information, please treat this as a two-tier question: my specific combination of conutries involved; and the general use across continents. The specific countries involved are Australia (as the overseas country) and Austria (my home country).

---

On a side note, this is the first time I have to deal with cheques. I am in my thirties and cheques aren't a thing in my country anymore. So, I am not familiar with the specific nomenclature, so please excuse my general ignorance in these matters.

Comment: As a general rule **no**, unfortunately.  As a rule you cannot deposit checks from other countries.  I suggest, quickly telephone (any) bank in Austria and ask them - there just may be some solution.  Fees will be high.

Comment: I asked my bank back in Austria: they will accept Australian cheques, however, for a very steep fee.

Comment: ah so they WILL accept one - well, that's something.

Comment: 9,50 EUR fixed fee plus 0.2 % booking fee (at least 14,27 max 186,95). This is insane. But yes, they accept. Nevertheless, I try to avoid taking the cheques home with me.

Comment: fascinating, thanks for tha - actually I thought it would be worse!